# Graph connectedness assignment

Tags: algorithm, graph

Does anyone know an algorithm for the following problem:

> Given a undirected connected graph find the number of ways in which 2
>   distinct edges can be cut such that the graph becomes disconnected.

I think a part of the problem (which I know an algorithm for) is calculating the number of ways in which 1 line can be cut so that it becomes disconnected. Then computing how these can be grouped with other lines gets the value `(M-K)*K + K*(K-1)/2`, `M` = no. of edges, `K` = no. of 1 edge cuts.

The part that I don't know how to do is finding the number of other ways to cut 2 line, for example in the graph that has only the cycle `1 - 2 - 3 - 1` any combination of the edges is a valid way of cutting lines to make the graph disconnected.

I coded the part of the program that finds all the 1 edge cuts and then I split the graph into biconnected components by removing those edges. I tried writing something for the second part, made 2 versions for that, but none of them got the right answer on every test.

Additional information about this homework problem:
 * The number of edges is < 100,000
 * The number of vertexes is < 2000
 * The program should run maximum 2 seconds on any graph with the above restrictions
 * There can be multiple edges between 2 vertexes.

I can do the first part in O(N+M). I guess the complexity for the second part should be maximum O(N*M).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for all [edge cuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) containing two edges. Such edge cuts only exist if the graph is at most [2-edge-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph).

The paper "[Efficient algorithm for finding all minimal edge cuts of a nonoriented graph](http://www.springerlink.com/content/x27057373428w2k0/)" by Karzanov and Timofeev contains an algorithm for computing all minimal edge cuts of a graph. From a brief look, it seems to me as if the algorithm can also be used to find cuts with a specified number of edges (for example, 2 edges). The complexity of the algorithm is O(lambda n^2), where lambda is the number of edges in the desired cuts (in your case, 2) and n is the number of vertices.

Comment: N^2 would be a very good complexity for the problem. I'll read about that algorithm :).

Answer (score 0):

The trivial solution: for all pairs of edges remove them from the graph and see if it is still connected. It's O(n^3) but should work.

Comment: I would need something faster, the number of edges is < 100000 and the number of vertexes is < 2000

Comment: How do you know you need something faster? Implement this first and see how it works. 

It is clear that you need at least O(n^2), otherwise you will fail to consider some pair of vertices and we could construct a graph where that particular pair of vertices disconnects the graph.

Since you also have to determine connectivity I bet the O(N^3) is close to optimal if not optimal.

Comment: How much do you think the program will run for the number of edges = 100 000?

Comment: Well, 100 000^3 = 1 000 000 000 000 000 = 10^15. Assuming "1" is equal to a microsecond (not a bad assumption) that gives your 31 years. I guess you need something faster.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is an extension of the 2-edge connectivity problem. To make sure that any edge `(v, w)` in the Graph is not a bridge, we find a back-edge from vertices `adjacent to w and including w`  going to `ancestor of v`. Here, ancestor means the vertices which were discovered before `v`.
Now, if there is only one such back-edge then `that back-edge and (v, w)` when removed will make the graph disconnected.